# Making A Call Using .Call file from Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Hello thank you in advance for your help.
 
I just installed chan_dongle with asterisk using one of the tutorials viewed this site. At the moment I can make and receive calls using a softphone, but you, I would like to make a call automatically asterisk.
 
by the time I have.

**Extensions.conf**

```
; Asterisk basic conf files
; By Giovanni Bosa - giovbs@gmail.com -
; Build 01/01/2013

[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=no
clearglobalvars=no

[globals]
LINE1=SIP/101



[FromDongle]
exten => +584147390386,1,Dial(${LINE1},50)
same => n,Hangup()

exten => sms,1,Verbose(Incoming SMS from ${CALLERID(num)} ${BASE64_DECODE(${SMS_BASE64})})
exten => sms,n,System(echo '${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)} - ${DONGLENAME} - ${CALLERID(num)}$
exten => sms,n,Hangup()

exten => ussd,1,Verbose(Incoming USSD: ${BASE64_DECODE(${USSD_BASE64})})
exten => ussd,n,System(echo '${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)} - ${DONGLENAME}: ${BASE64_DECODE($
exten => ussd,n,Hangup()

[modulo01]
exten => _X.,1,Dial(Dongle/modulo01/${EXTEN},60)
exten => _X.,n,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en/textveloper)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()

[oreilly]
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
exten => _X.,n,Playback(demo-moreinfo)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

and copy a file every time i want to make an outgoing call located in var/spool/asterisk/outbound/

**makcall.call**

```
Channel: SIP/101
MaxRetries: 1
RetryTime: 20
WaitTime: 10
Context: oreilly
Extension: 101
Priority: 1
```

using these 2 files how can I make a call to the number 4247054406? without having to use the softphone to dial the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in makecall.call

```
Channel: Dongle/modulo01/4247054406
```

Note, create dialler by non-expert is very bad idea, you will have alot of other issues.